# Como não selecionar linhas com valores entre uma lista de valores informada

Tags: sql, oracle

Ao invés de utilizar o operador lógico de diferente **`!=`**, gostaria de utilizar um código que efetuasse a consulta desconsiderando uma lista de valores tal como no **`In`** só que o inverso.

```
Select from teste where teste1 (código) ('x','y','a','g')
```

Estou utilizando o **`!=`** mas preciso escrever muitas linhas de comando pra trazer o que preciso, pois são vários dados que não preciso que seja consultado.

Comment: POR FAVOR, NÃO ESCREVA TUDO EM CAIXA ALTA. PARECE QUE VOCÊ TÁ GRITANDO.

Comment: Em SQL, o contrario de `IN` é o `NOT IN`.

Comment: [Como NÃO fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Comment: Valeu @MarceloBonifazio ! Corrigido!

Answer (score 1):

Use **`Not In`**

```
Select from Tabela where Coluna Not In ('x', 'y', 'a', 'g')
```